# Can't Get message box to work in method with a for loop

Tags: c#

I've gotten the program to work, but the kicker is I have to put a message box in to tell the user that he entered an incorrect number or description and I can't seem to make it work. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlexableOrder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int [] itemNum = { 112, 123, 134, 213, 224, 235 };
            double[] price = { 16.95, 10.95, 14.25, 21.95, 45.99, 89.99 };
            string[] description = { "plate", "cup", "bowl", "vase", "planter", "statue" };

            string getstrItem;
            int getintItem;

            getstrItem = Convert.ToString(txtOrder.Text);
            bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(getstrItem, out getintItem);
            getDetails(getintItem,itemNum,price);
            getDetails(getstrItem, description, price);

        }
        public void getDetails(int itemNumber, int [] item, double [] metPrice )
        {
            bool statement = false;

            for (int index = 0; index < item.Length; ++index)
            {
                if (itemNumber == item[index])
                {
                    txtDetails.Text = string.Format("Item number is {0} and price is {1}", itemNumber, metPrice[index]);
                    statement = true;
                }
            }
        }
        private void getDetails(string itemNumber, string[] description, double [] Price )
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < description.Length; ++index)
            {
                if (itemNumber == description[index])
                    txtDetails.Text = string.Format("The item description is {0} and price is {1}", description[index], Price[index]);
            }      
        }

    }
}
```

I tried putting an else statement in but when I noticed it was just skipping the first if statement because it was the wrong number going to the else.

Immediately putting the message box, even if I entered the right number in it would display the right thing in the text box then put up the message box.

Comment: I can't figure out, where you display the `MessageBox` or do you mean by `MessageBox` your `txtDetails` field?

Comment: where it should go honestly, I think it has to be in both of the methods if the user inputs the wrong description or item number

Comment: Well, if you're trying to use your method, I'd prefer to use a `bool` variable, which will be checked after your for loop executed.

Comment: dang i feel stupid now.

Comment: Okay, I give you a short explanation: User input => Goes into Method => Method checks user input against each item in your array => If the For loop finds a match set the variable to bool and then break the loop. If the for loop doesn't find a match set the variable to false. After the loop check this variable `true``false` on false set `MessageBox`

Comment: now my problem is if i enter in a description it still pops up the message box from the first method. I usually don't have this many problems with programs but this one is getting to me

Comment: Ofc it does, you assign these two methods in your button click. Both methods will fire.

Comment: well then i guess my question is how do i call one or the other instead of calling both if the user inputs a string or a integer.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out

Comment: @AndySwinney In the event handler for the button, check it using an if statment.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit.